# How to display PointGeometryModel3D using Helix.Toolkit.Wpf.SharpDx

Tags: wpf, point-clouds, helix-3d-toolkit

I have a problem displaying a 3D pointcloud in my WPF application. I want to display the corner points of a 2x2x2 box, but my view stays empty and just the black background is shown.

I've compared my code to several examples, but I could not see any serious difference, e.g:
[How to plot 3D colored points with Helix toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334282) or
https://qiita.com/systeman/items/0e539e606def64ed6c3f
and many more.

I've reduced the code to the minimal to eliminate as much sources of error as possible. So this is what's left, but still not working:

*MainWindow.xaml.cs:*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    public PointGeometry3D Geometry
    {
        get
        {
            var vc = new Vector3Collection();
            var id = new IntCollection();

            vc.Add(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
            id.Add(0);
            vc.Add(new Vector3(2, 0, 0));
            id.Add(1);
            vc.Add(new Vector3(0, 2, 0));
            id.Add(2);
            vc.Add(new Vector3(0, 0, 2));
            id.Add(3);
            vc.Add(new Vector3(2, 2, 0));
            id.Add(4);
            vc.Add(new Vector3(0, 2, 2));
            id.Add(5);
            vc.Add(new Vector3(2, 0, 2));
            id.Add(6);
            vc.Add(new Vector3(2, 2, 2));
            id.Add(7);

            var g = new PointGeometry3D() { Positions = vc, Indices = id };
            return g;
        }

    }
}
```

*MainWindow.xaml:*

```
<hx:Viewport3DX>
    <hx:Viewport3DX.Camera>
    <hx:PerspectiveCamera Position="0,0,10" LookDirection="0,0,-1" UpDirection="0,1,0"/>
    </hx:Viewport3DX.Camera>
    <hx:AmbientLight3D/>
    <hx:PointGeometryModel3D Geometry="{Binding Geometry}" Size="2 2" Color="Bisque"/>
</hx:Viewport3DX>
```

Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind or set the DefaultEffectsManager

Comment: Works now. Thank you!